# R studio packages on mojave have 'non-zero exit status'

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, macos-mojave, bioconductor

I haven't used R for a while. Now I need to work with it again and in the meantime I updated to mac os mojave. Also, bioconductor apparently switched sth in their installations and we now have to use biocmanager instead of bioclite. Anyways, I run into several installation errors and have no idea what to do. I just downloaded xcode hoping that this was the problem but I still get the following errors:

```
> library(DESeq2)
Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘DESeq2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 es gibt kein Paket namens ‘Hmisc’
> install.packages("Hmisc")
also installing the dependencies ‘acepack’, ‘data.table’

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  kann URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES' nicht öffnen
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation
  of C/C++/Fortran: ‘acepack’ ‘data.table’ ‘Hmisc’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source packages ‘acepack’, ‘data.table’, ‘Hmisc’

versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/acepack_1.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 34848 bytes (34 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 34 KB

versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/data.table_1.12.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4948391 bytes (4.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.7 MB

versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Hmisc_4.4-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 744545 bytes (727 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 727 KB

* installing *source* package ‘acepack’ ...
** Paket ‘acepack’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c ace.f -o ace.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [ace.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘acepack’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/acepack’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘acepack’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
** Paket ‘data.table’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** using staged installation
zlib 1.2.8 is available ok
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c assign.c -o assign.o
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [assign.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/data.table’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘acepack’, ‘data.table’ are not available for package ‘Hmisc’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Hmisc’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Hmisc’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/7y/tklmw3f51rz8292j144_70680000gn/T/RtmpacLY8N/downloaded_packages’
```

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I am running Mojave on my laptops, and I was able to use [this guide](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/) to get things working.

**Try following the steps on that guide.**

However, I had to use a slightly different `Makevars` file because I'm not on the most up-to-date OS.

Here is the contents of my `~/.R/Makevars` file.

```
CFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CCFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CXXFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CPPFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include

CXX14 = /usr/local/clang7/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -nostdinc++ -I/usr/local/clang7/include/c++/v1
SHLIB_CXX14LD = /usr/local/clang7/bin/clang++ -L/usr/local/clang7/lib

FLIBS=""
F77="/usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran"
FC="/usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran"
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't work out, though. After adding all the lines to the makevars file it says "permission denied"

Comment: Are you using brew? Try `brew doctor`?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to R preferences > Packages and unchecking "Use secure download method for HTTP", it looks like this is a default parameter that unables opening the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

I could fix the problem by typing the following into my terminal:

```
brew update && brew reinstall r
```